# 80s/90s Sci fi cartoon with artwork similar to Moebius', with a space journey atmosphere and a blue spaceship flying through the desert

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, soft-sci-fi

I've got memories of a cartoon, I'm pretty sure I saw it on Cartoon Network a few times very early in the morning but I looked on the wiki list of shows and it's not there. I thought it was called *Lazarus* but nothing comes up.

I don't remember much except the intro has a rounded blue spaceship flying through the desert, the crew is both human and some alien creatures. The artwork reminds me of Moebius but it's not *The Time Masters*, it looks kinda similar but a little bit simpler, it also reminds me of *The Herculoids* for some reason, maybe the colour scheme or setting.

That's really all I know, it would've been on air pre-1995. Definitely not an anime but don't know whether it's American or European. Any help greatly appreciated, remember the show having a really space journey atmosphere, would love to find it.

Answer (score 6):

I would say [Spartakus and The Sun Beneath The Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spartakus_and_the_Sun_Beneath_the_Sea). The series itself is from the 80's and the scene of a blue vessel travelling above sands matches, plus the artwork is very distinctive

[image]

Comment: And one could mistake "Lazarus" for "Spartakus" indeed. Good catch, +1 :)